# The bag includes a minifigure, whites, grays, and black

Tags: set-identification

windows, doors, and blue opalesence parts.  minifigure with dark gray suit but I have no clue on these.[image]

Answer (score 6):

Using orange [Tile Round 2x2 with hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15535) and white [Brick 1x16](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2465) I found [60228-1 Deep Space Rocket and Launch Control](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60228-1). This set also has windows and rounded white pieces visible in the bag.

[image]